# Method before keyboard gesture in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a MenuItem which in which items are binded to some keyboard input gesture i.e. we have a functionality of calculate, which we can either do by opening menu via mouse or directly pressing f6.

If I run similarly we have a lot of MenuItems with keyboard gesture binded to it, I want a function to run before we call the calculate method with keyboard gestures. I don't want to add method one by one to all the MenuItems. So is there any way to do so ?

I'm just expecting a way to run a method before any keyboard gesture is called.

Comment: Previewkeydown. But there are likely some complications to using this if you have anything like textboxes where the user inputs.